# Magento Swatches in Custom Theme Blanco, not changing the product image

Tags: magento, colors

I´m having problems with the configurable products changing the product image in the product page wnen is selected from the drop down. I have followed every tutorial but i cannot resolve the problem.
With the theme default theme rwd is work fine but the problem is with the Blanco theme.

I see in the code of the rwd that the javascript function is loaded, but in the Blanco theme this javacript function is not loaded.
 $j(document).on(‘product-media-loaded’, function() { ConfigurableMediaImages.init(‘base_image’); ConfigurableMediaImages.setImageFallback(26258, $j.parseJSON(‘{“option_labels”:{“azul”:{“configurable_product”:

Could anybody help me?
Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to follow below link and it will be done.

https://www.bemaged.com/en/blog/use-magento-swatches-in-custom-theme/

And if it work then accept this answer.

Comment: Sorry, not works ... I think that is an issue in my template.